# Solution to second order non constant differential equation without first derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Cheers!

So I am studying the book ‘Introduction to quantum mechanics’ by David J. Griffiths for my introductory course of quantum mechanics. On page 51 at the bottom it introduces the differential expression:
\begin{equation}
\Phi’’ = \xi^2 \Phi
\end{equation}
Without saying much further, it presents the general solution as:
\begin{equation}
\Phi = A e^{-\xi^2/2} + B e^{\xi^2/2}
\end{equation}
Indeed, when I check this solution with the differential equation, I can see that it can match it. However I am still completely missing on how one would arrive from the differential equation to the general solution.

I have already been trying several different methods, all unsuccessful, so I would indeed appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: Is $\Phi$ a function of $\xi$?

Comment: Yes, so $\Phi(\xi)$.

Comment: $e^{\xi^2/2},\ e^{-\xi^2/2}$ are not solutions of the considered equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving $y''-(\xi^2-K)y=0$ we have solution
$$y=Ae^{\sqrt{\xi^2-K}}+Be^{-\sqrt{\xi^2-K}}~~~~~,~~~~~\xi^2-K>0$$
with $\xi>>K$
$$\sqrt{\xi^2-K}=\sqrt{-K}\sqrt{1-\dfrac{\xi^2}{K}}=\sqrt{-K}\left(1-\dfrac{\xi^2}{K}\right)^\frac12\approx\sqrt{-K}\left(1-\frac12\dfrac{\xi^2}{K}\right)\approx\sqrt{-K}\left(-\frac12\dfrac{\xi^2}{K}\right)\approx\dfrac{\xi^2}{2i\sqrt{K}}\approx\dfrac{\xi^2}{2}$$

Comment: How do you get the solution to $y''-(\xi^2-K)y=0$ though?

Comment: @Tony , its from the book. However its strange, because first they simplify, and then they set up the dofferential equation presented above, to which they simply go ahead and drop the solution. So the explanation given here actually suprises me a bit in the sense that it actually requires you to go back to before the simplificiation.